# Using the LQGRegulator to build a human operator model

Tags: control-systems

I'm trying to build a human operator model using an [optimal control model](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=1099842&tag=1) in Mathematica:
[image: Human operator model]

The vehicle dynamics are given by

```
a = {{-2, 0}, {1, 0}};
b = {{0}, {1}};
c = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
d = {{0}, {1}};
```

with noise and cost weightings

```
w = {{4}};
v = {{0.0025}};
q = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}};
r = {{1}};
```

I generated the state space model and added the time delay ($T_d = 0.2s$) using

```
ssm = StateSpaceModel[{a, b, c, d}]
td = TransferFunctionModel[SystemsModelDelay[.2]];
ssmWithDelay = SystemsModelSeriesConnect[td, ssm];
```

Now I am trying model the Kalman estimator and gains ($-l^*$) using a LQG regulator

```
k = LQGRegulator[{ssm, 1, 1}, {w, v}, {q, r}] // StateSpaceModel
```

which results in the error

```
The number of columns in {{},{}} is not equal to the length of {{4}}
```

I think my problem must be with the noise and cost weightings, but I'm not sure where I went wrong?

Comment: In the figure, the system 'vehicle dynamics' has two inputs - the disturbance and the feedback input, so probably the b and d matrices need to have two columns as well.

Comment: I thought the disturbance is represented by the $\mathbf{W}$ noise term in $\dot{x}(t) = \mathbf{A}x(t) + \mathbf{B}u(t) + \mathbf{W}(t)$

Comment: That is not correct. In general the B matrix is [Bf, Bw, Be] corresponding to feedback, noise, and exogenous (other deterministic) inputs. Refer to the 3rd bullet point in 'Details and Options' in the ref page for LQGRegulator.

Comment: I also think the dimensions of v is incorrect. In LQGRegulator you specify that only the first output is noisy  but v has dimensions 2x2.

Comment: Thanks Suba, I've changed the dimensions of v.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the noise and the input $u(t)$ enter the system in the same way you can simply use

```
ssm = SystemsModelExtract[ssm, {1, 1}]
```

before calling `LQGRegulator`

Comment: Thanks Bob, that seems to work well. If I understand correctly, when noise and input u (t) enter the system in the same way, `{1,1}` "doubles" the input, to satisfy the requirement of `k = LQGRegulator[{ssm1, 1, 1}, {w, v}, {q, r}]` having one noisy measurement and one input?

Comment: @Gerrit, your are right that the input gets "doubled". In general, for the specification SystemsModelExtract[sys, spec, ...], there would be _n_ independent input channels of input _i_ in the resulting system, where n = Count[spec, i]. So here {1, 1} would create a determinsitic feedback *input* and a noisy *input*. Just to clarify, both are inputs to the system.