# Using transfer function model to generate state space model

Tags: control-systems

I am trying to generate the state space model for the following system:

[image]

However, the following code does not generate the state space model I expect:

```
tf = TransferFunctionModel[{{1/s}, {1/(s + 2)}}, s]
ssm = StateSpaceModel[tf]
```

What I'm expecting is

$A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
$B = \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$
$C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$
$D = \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

but what I'm getting is

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$
$B = \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$
$C = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$
$D = \begin{bmatrix}  0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

The state equations are:

$$\dot{x_1}(t) = -2 x_1 (t) + w_1 (t) $$
$$\dot{x_2}(t) = x_1(t) + u(t)$$
$$y_1(t) = x_2(t)$$
$$y_2(t) = \dot{x}_2(t)$$

where $w_1(t)$ denotes the white noise added to the system, and $x_2(t)$ denotes the system error, $e$.

How should I enter my transfer function model to generate such a state space model?

Comment: I think you have a typo, because the matrices you expect do not give the transfer function you started with. In any case, look at the option StateSpaceRealization and see if that will solve your problem.

Comment: It looks like you are entering it in the form TransferFunctionModel[{num,den},s]. I don't see the relation between this num, den and your picture. What variable is the input and what variable is the output of your transfer function?

Comment: No, it's not {num,den}, but a matrix, as it's a MIMO system with one input and two outputs. The input to the system is the white noise, and two outputs are $e$ and $\dot{e}$. I'll add the state equations to hopefully make more sense.

Comment: The state is {x1, x2}. So your C matrix says that $y_2(t)=x_2(t)$, not that $y_2(t)=\dot{x}_2(t)$ as in your state equation.

Comment: But more fundamentally, how is u ("control input") calculated from $e$ and $\dot{e}$? If you don't specify this, then you have a 2-input ($u$ and white noise) and 2-output ($e$ and $\dot{e}$) system. So you have neither the state equations nor the state space equations correct.

Comment: $y_2(t) = \dot{x}_2(t) = x_1(t) + u(t)$, which is why I'm expecting the first C matrix. As shown in the figure, $u(t)$ and the white noise are added to get a single input to the system. If you would like more context on the _Human_ block, refer to [this related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21661/using-the-lqgregulator-to-build-a-human-operator-model).

Comment: x1(t) = Exp[-2 t] is not white noise.

Comment: @SubaThomas, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. How is $x_1(t) = e^{-2t}$ ? By the way, while it didn't solve my problem above, your first comment was quite helpful in fixing some of my other "transfer function to state space" conversions.

Comment: I just solved the first state equation. From the block diagram, I think the equation should be $\dot{x}_{1}(t)=-2 x_{1}(t)+w(t)$ where $w(t)$ is the white noise input. The system has two inputs - one the deterministic feedback input $u(t)$ and the other the white noise $w(t)$.

Comment: You're correct: there is a term $w_1(t)$. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System *sys1* has inputs $u(t)$ and the white noise.

```
sys1 = StateSpaceModel@TransferFunctionModel[{{1, 1/((s + 2))}}, s];
```

We are only interested in the input $u(t)$ and so we extract the subsystem corresponding to that.

```
sys2 = SystemsModelExtract[sys1, 1];
```

The desired output of the overall system is 1) $e(t)$ which is the integral of the output of *sys1*  and 2) $\dot{e}(t)$ which can just be taken as the output of *sys1*. So I am going to construct a system that I plan to connect in series with *sys2*.

```
sys3 = TransferFunctionModel[{{1/s}, {1}}, s];
```

Now the series connection will give the desired result.

```
SystemsModelSeriesConnect[sys2, sys3]
```

StateSpaceModel[{{{-2, 0}, {1, 0}}, {{0}, {1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 
    0}}, {{0}, {1}}}, 
   SamplingPeriod -> None, SystemsModelLabels -> None]

Comment: In _sys1_ if you remove StateSpaceModel and then wrap the final result in StateSpaceModel, you will get yet another i-o equivalent state-space represenation. The interal dynamics of these are different and they are sometimes very very important.

Answer (score 1):

An answer based on the discussion above. For the system with inputs comprising of the deterministic feedback input $u(t)$ and the white noise input $w(t)$, and outputs $e(t)$ and $\dot{e}(t)$, a state-space representation would be

```
StateSpaceModel@TransferFunctionModel[{{1/s, 1/(s (s + 2))}, {1, 1/(s + 2)}}, s]
```

which gives StateSpaceModel[{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, -2}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 
    0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 
    0}}}, SamplingPeriod ->None, SystemsModelLabels -> None]

You could then use this to design a feedback controller.

Comment: While I believe that you're right, can you please explain how you got to that conclusion? For reference, I'm working from pg. 177 of [this report](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1665239/NASA%20Report%20Baron%20Kleinman%20OCM.pdf) (on my dropbox). The [original link](http://naca.larc.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19710021897&qs=N%3D4294961077%2B4294866697%26No%3D10%26Nn%3D4294966753%257CNASA-Center%257CAmes%2BResearch%2BCenter) is down for maintenance.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. That helps. State-space representations are not unique, so we could go through two different routes and end up with two different but input-output equivalent state-space representations. I will give detailed explanations in my next answer. I am leaving this answer as is, because it is also correct.

Comment: I expected there would be equivalent state-space representations, but wanted to know how I can use Mathematica to produce the same matrices as in the reference. Your other answer does this beautifully, thank you.